# Difference between "My Mac 32-bit" and "My Mac 64-bit" in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, 64-bit

I have a Cocoa project that I recently imported into Xcode 4. I notice two Schemes for each of my specific build targets, one for 32-bit, and one for 64-bit. My Project settings are set to "Standard (32/64-bit Intel)".

When I select the "My Mac 32-bit" Scheme, does this compile it for 32-bit machines, and selecting "My Mac 64-bit", then compiles it for 64-bit machines? If I select the "My Mac 64-bit" Scheme, will it no longer run on 32-bit machines at all?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scheme setting changes what happens in Xcode when you click Run, Build, etc. The architecture settings are changed inside the project settings, visible in your screen shot. Only there would you be able to chose "32-bit only" or "64-bit only". And it is likely that if you publish a binary with 64-bit only it wouldn't run on 32-bit machines. You would have to build for both platforms and include both binaries in a single Universal binary to get backwards compatibility with 32-bit-only Macs.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X allow you to run 64 bits software on 32 bits Mac OS X and the reverse, 32 bits software on 64 bits Mac OS X. If your software use a lot of memory, don't hesitate to choose the 64 bits option. Else, you should benchmark to see what is better, as 64 bits software on a 32 bits kernel tend to have a bit of a performance hit.

some more info about it : http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised too at first, because it doesn`t work at all on Windows. The reason Apple can get away with it, iirc, is that they do not have problems (or just don't care) with buggy third party drivers/old software, since they drop legacy support as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't think you can get the "> 4 GB memory for app X" with a 32-bit EFI, however. The 64-bit app my run on 64, but not with that benefit unless you have 64-bit hardware? Does that sound right?

Comment: That sound right, but I must admit I am at the limit of my knowledge for the Mac platform.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the scheme setting from "My Mac 32-bit" to "My Mac 64-bit" does not change how the app is compiled. It only changes what binary version is launched immediately on your machine for testing or profiling. The app continues to have both binaries for 32 and 64 bit compiled and included in the final product for shipping as a universal application.

Comment: This is true except whether the app is compiled as 32bit, 64bit, or both, is controlled by project build settings.  The scheme settings let you choose which project build settings are used so you can create a scheme called "32 bit" pointing to 32 bit project build settings, and yet still choose to run that scheme in "My Mac 64-bit" mode for debugging.  Debugger probably won't be able to launch in that case but I haven't tested it.

Comment: If you change your build settings to only have 32 or 64, the options to launch in the other disappear from the pop-up. The pop-up is smart enough to know what is available for the project.